# Problem in calculating Area under curve in R

Tags: r, classification, svm, roc

I have a dataset of 50 samples and divided that into training and testing datasets. I applied SVM to the training dataset and predicted a model.

Below, you can find `svm` column from training data and `Predicted` column from testing data.

```
data <- structure(list(Samples = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", 
"Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7", "Sample8", "Sample9", "Sample10", 
"Sample11", "Sample12", "Sample13", "Sample14", "Sample15", "Sample16", 
"Sample17", "Sample18", "Sample19", "Sample20", "Sample21", "Sample22", 
"Sample23", "Sample24", "Sample25", "Sample26", "Sample27", "Sample28", 
"Sample29", "Sample30", "Sample31", "Sample32", "Sample33", "Sample34", 
"Sample35", "Sample36", "Sample37", "Sample38", "Sample39", "Sample40", 
"Sample41", "Sample42", "Sample43", "Sample44", "Sample45", "Sample46", 
"Sample47", "Sample48", "Sample49"), svm = c("typeA", "typeA", 
"typeA", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeA", 
"typeB", "typeA", "typeB", "typeA", "typeB", "typeA", "typeB", 
"typeB", "typeB", "typeA", "typeA", "typeB", "typeA", "typeB", 
"typeA", "typeB", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", 
"typeA", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", 
"typeB", "typeA", "typeB", "typeA", "typeB", "typeB", "typeA", 
"typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeB"), Predicted = c("typeA", 
"typeA", "typeA", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", 
"typeA", "typeB", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeB", "typeA", 
"typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeA", "typeA", "typeB", "typeA", 
"typeB", "typeA", "typeB", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", 
"typeA", "typeA", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", "typeA", 
"typeB", "typeB", "typeA", "typeA", "typeB", "typeB", "typeB", 
"typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeA", "typeB")), row.names = c(NA, 
-49L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I added `pred2` column by doing like below:

```
data$pred2 <- ifelse(data$svm=="typeA", 1, 0)
```

I used `pROC` package to get the `AUC`.

```
library(pROC)
res.roc <- roc(data$Predicted, data$pred2)
plot.roc(res.roc, print.auc = TRUE, main="")
```

[image]

I have seen several posts, which tell that AUC (Area under the curve) tells better about the performance of the model than Accuracy.

I'm confused whether the way I calculated AUC is truly an AUC or Accuracy? Can anyone tell whether this is right or not? Is this enough to check the performance of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question would be better posed to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), but accuracy != AUC.

Here's an article that describes the differences and some other, perhaps better, metrics for evaluating the performance of machine learning algorithms: https://neptune.ai/blog/f1-score-accuracy-roc-auc-pr-auc

The short of it is that accuracy requires choosing a cutoff, whereas AUC does not.

The pROC package uses the `trapezoid rule` to calculate AUC.  Check the help for the `pROCH::auc` function, it has lots of information and references.

Comment: thanks a lot. May I know with the above available data how to calculate AUC?

Comment: Added this to the answer.

Comment: thanq very much !!